# Python3 subprocess executes command in old shell - sftp problems

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am trying to create some kind of ping of a sftp server and report when the connection fails with python3.

The command that I am trying to execute is this one :

```
sftp -P port user@host <<< exit > /dev/null 2>&1
```

It works when I execute it locally with all my shell (sh 4.3, bash, zsh) on arch, it works when I execute it in subprocess.check_call([command], shell=True) (also on my computer) but it doesn't work on the server because /bin/sh is used by check_call and the version installed does not allow redirection like "<<< exit".

I get this error : /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

I really need the "exit" keyword passed to the process once it is connected to the sftp to automatically close the connection. For that, I need to either find the correct command to pass to the old /bin/sh or tell subprocess to use /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh.

Anybody knows how I can fix this ?

server 3.16.0-60-generic #80~14.04.1-Ubuntu

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

/bin/sh was actually redirected to /bin/dash. I changed it to /bin/bash and now it works.